# Sending a embeds from Script to Discord via Webhook - Components not working

Tags: javascript, discord, webhooks

I'm facing an issue and i also tested it via -curl with no other results.
Basically i'm sending a json like this:

```
  "embeds": [
    {
      "title": "A title",
      "description": "A description",
      "color": 16711680,
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "first name",
          "value": "value",
          "inline": true
        },
        {
          "name": "second name",
          "value": "value",
          "inline": true
        },
        {
          "name": "third name",
          "value": "value",
          "inline": true
        }
      ],
      "footer": {
        "text": "Powered by xxx",
        "icon_url": "a url"
      }
    }
  ],
  "components": [
    {
      "type": 1,
      "components": [
        {
          "type": 2,
          "label": "Click me!",
          "style": 5,
          "url": "a link"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

It works fine as it should but i'm not able to show the buttons from components in the message nor from App script or -curl

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED
You cannot use "components" who a webhook only.
**It requires an application-owned webhook**